# Can not load Opencv libraries in necessitas

Tags: android, c++, qt, opencv

I try to use the camera in a necessitas project using OpenCV. I have this on the .pro file

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin/OpenCV-2.3.1/include \
                C:/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules

LIBS += C:/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so \
        C:/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so \
        C:/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi/libopencv_androidcamera.a \
        C:/OpenCV-2.3.1-android-bin/OpenCV-2.3.1/libs/armeabi/libopencv_calib3d.a \ ...
```

and I call the camera when I press a button with this:

```
void MainWindow::on_foto_clicked()
{
    CvCapture * camera = cvCreateCameraCapture( 0 );
    IplImage * image = cvQueryFrame( camera );

    cvReleaseCapture( &camera );
}
```

When I run it and It tries to run on the device, a samsung galaxy gio with Android 2.3.4, I get this:

```
W/System.err(17481): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1963]:    94 could not load needed library 'libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so' for 'libGeopei.so' (load_library[1105]: Library 'libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so' not found)
```

Am I missing to load any library or include?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to integrate OpenCV into Qt Creator Android project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27562311/how-to-integrate-opencv-into-qt-creator-android-project)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to manually copy `libnative_camera_r2.2.2.so` to `/android/libs/armeabi-v7a` directory.

Then, modify the `QtActivity.java` file in order to load the libs manually at startup:

```
String appPath = getApplication().getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(); 

//application path
System.load(appPath+"/../lib/libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so");
System.load(appPath+"/../lib/libopencv_java.so");
```

Comment: I try this and first I added those lines to the end of loadApplication method and then to the end of startApp method and I'm getting the same message, then I paste it at the beggining of startApp method and sent me a fatal exception. Am I pasting it in the wrong method?

Comment: Is any dependency missing in your app? Can you try re-installing Ministro from android market?

Comment: I don't think so, before trying to add Opencv the app was running fine. Hwere should I add those lines( which method ) maybe that is the problem right now. I also try to reinstall ministro. Thanks

Comment: I reinstall Ministro and have the same problem.

Comment: hi did u found the solution ? if u found thn plz share it.. as m gtting sme issue...